# Get Moving Average for crypto currency from Coinbase API

Tags: coinbase-api

Trying to get moving average values like EMA(9), EMA(20), EMA(20) etc. for any given crypto from Coinbase API in real time for use in a bot trading app.

Is this possible?

Any direction to documentation / guidance or sample will help.

Not really sure how to go about getting this kind of data

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the pro api.
Start with the [candles](https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/exchange/reference/exchangerestapi_getproductcandles) endpoint and loop through it.

if you have specific questions about your code later, that's another question.